# page rotate -90° width = height

Tags: css, rotation

A silly question here.

I'm rotating a div -90°, how can I set the width of that div as the height of the page? If I do it normally it keeps the width of the screen and it keeps scrolling vertically, all I want is to scroll just horizontally.

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateZ(0px);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateZ(0px);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateZ(0px);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateZ(0px);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n2z51je7/

Thanks!

Comment: Please update the question with enough code and/or provide an online example to demonstrate the issue in action.

Comment: @HashemQolami I added a JSFIDDLE.

Comment: Does this help? https://jsfiddle.net/hashem/n2z51je7/2/